# Angular route 1.3 removes trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, migration, angular-routing

**17-MAR-2015 edit** : seems this is a hashbang-mode link-rewriting issue of some sort
Didn't find much on migration notes 1.2 > 1.3 about changes in Hashbang mode, but this is what I observed:

- 1.2 : in Angular 1.2 a link to index.html (href="index.html") yields http:///index.html consistently
- 1.3 : In Angular 1.3 a link to index.html (href="index.html") yields http:///index.html#/  on first hit, http:///index.html# on second (loosing the trailing slash)
  [solution is to use href="#/index.html"]

*Any explanations are very welcome !*

---

I have this simple setup for basic navigation in an Angular spa with the angular-route module. I used it *successfully with Angular 1.2.17* but **fails with Angular 1.3.14** because **it removes the trailing /**.

I'm stumped as actually the first hit with Angular 1.3.x works but the second fails.
See also plunker examples (same code, one uses Angular 1.2.x , other Angular 1.3.x):

- v1.3.x : http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/NVTfBWXcbQaP6XlRVgN8/#/
- v1.2.x : http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/hhHltoSnvkkeEB0nBGma/#/

Content of my javascript file:

```
var logBookApp = angular.module('LogBookApp', ['ngRoute']);

logBookApp.config(
    function ( $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'tmpls/home.tmpl.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl as logbookHome' })
        .when('/LogBook/:id', { templateUrl: 'tmpls/logbookform.tmpl.html', controller: 'LogBookFormCtrl as logbookForm' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });
```

Content of html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Logbook tracking</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="LogBookApp">
  <div ng-controller="LogBookCtrl as logbook">
    <a href="index.html">Test direct link home !</a>
    <a href="#">Test hash tag link!</a>
  </div>    
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
  <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/LogBookapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are welcome !
I've tried to use the angular-resource module (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for specifying to NOT to remove trailingslashes but this didn't work out.

```
app.config(['$resourceProvider', function($resourceProvider) {
  $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
}]);
```